# Disallow link To open in system Browser

Tags: c#, windows, webview, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am Using WebView in my windows 8.1 store app in which every (Target=_Blank) type link force a link to open in system browser I want to open it in a webview it self to restrict the link go outside the application is there any way to complete the action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily inject JavaScript that changes the target of anchors.

> Refer to this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/it-IT/37f760ff-c476-4602-b1c0-b7a62c484d6a/xaml-page-webview-control-injecting-javascript?forum=xmlandnetfx
>
> And this: http://irisclasson.com/2012/10/12/how-to-invoke-javascript-functions-in-a-webview-in-windows-store-apps/